# How can I create a iterable collection of constants with autocompletion and typing support in Python?

Tags: python, enums

Given several grouped sets of constants, e.g., animals:

```
# Pets
DOG = Animal(...)
CAT = Animal(...)

# Big cats
LION = Animal(...)
TIGER = Animal(...)
```

Any editor will provide auto-completion and typing support.  However, there is no way to iterate over pets and big cats without creating explicit lists of the constants (`pets = [DOG, CAT]`).  The same goes for static classes:

```
class Pets:
    DOG = Animal(...)
    CAT = Animal(...)
```

Turning them into dictionaries (`pets = {"DOG": Animal(...), "CAT": Animal(...)}`) will provide iteration support but not auto-completion for referring to single constants (`pets["DOG"]`).  Something like a `TypedDict` seems like it would help, but it cannot be instantiated.

Enums seem to offer the best solution, but they encapsulate constants in a wrapper class, and, in at least some editors, the values in the wrapper classes are not type hinted.

```
import enum

class Pets(enum.Enum):
    DOG = Animal(...)
    CAT = Animal(...)

dog = Pets.DOG.value  # Access single value with autocompletion

for member in Pets:  # Loop over values
    animal = member.value
```

Is there a way to achieve iterability, auto-completion for single constants, correct type-hinting, and preferably no wrapping classes?

It seems like a DIY solution based on a static class (see above) that inherits from a superclass that provides an iterator based on introspection would tick most boxes; however, I'd be unsure how to type hint the iterator correctly.

```
class CustomEnum:
    @classmethod
    def members():
        ...  # iterate over all attributes and filter out the generic ones

class Pets(CustomEnum):
    DOG = Animal(...)
    CAT = Animal(...)

dog = Pets.DOG  # Access single value with autocompletion

for animal in Pets.members():  # Loop over values
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using dataclasses to store all the constants under the same static class as it can be treated as a namespace.

You can iterate over all the fields of a dataclass with the `fields()` function.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields
from typing import Generator

@dataclass
class Animal:
    name: str

@dataclass(frozen=True, order=True, init=False) 
class Pets:
    DOG: Animal = Animal('dog')
    CAT: Animal = Animal('cat')
    FISH: Animal = Animal('fish')
    
    @staticmethod
    def members() -> Generator[Animal, None, None]:
        for f in fields(Pets):
            yield getattr(Pets, f.name)

# Single Instance
print(Pets.DOG)

# All members
for pet in Pets.members():
    print(pet)
```

A more dynamic approach would be to add all the instances of `Animal` into a list with metaprogramming, but this approach will store ALL the instances of animal, not just the ones that you want as constant.
This approach will require a mechanism to differentiate constants from typicial instances